# Maven Surefire report showing skipped Tests as pass

Tags: cucumber, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I was running testng suites against maven surefire plugin and noticed that when I run ex:Sanity Suite it displays not only the Sanity results but also the other suites test scenarios which had to be skipped and mention as pass. 
I am using cucumber testng runner to execute scripts based on tag names.In the screenshot below there are the same 9 scenarios that are executed for both suites however the actual tests are only done for their respective suite. Is this a surefire functionality to show pass for the rest of the feature that were supposed to be skipped?

Screenshot attached

[image]